# Separating a string in R into words

Tags: r, string

I am working on a movie dataset that has genres in the following format: "Animation|Sci-Fi", "Adventure|Animation|Children|Fantasy", etc.

I want to separate them into individual words, like "Animation" and "Sci-Fi"

I've tried using `str_split` in the `stringr` package, but it's not giving me what I want. I'm sure I'm using the wrong code. Could somebody give me some advice on how to proceed? Thanks.

Edit: I believe I'm supposed to give `str_split` a regular expression pattern, so I tried `str_extract(test_df$genres[1:20], "\\w+|\\w+")` for a test run, but I was not able to get what I need.

Comment: What code did you try and can you include it in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s <- "Animation|Sci-Fi|Adventure|Animation|Children|Fantasy";

# In base R
unlist(strsplit(s, "\\|"));
#[1] "Animation" "Sci-Fi"    "Adventure" "Animation" "Children"  "Fantasy"

# Using stringr
require(stringr);
unlist(str_split(s, "\\|"));
#[1] "Animation" "Sci-Fi"    "Adventure" "Animation" "Children"  "Fantasy"
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. I'm very bad with regular expressions--definitely would not have gotten that. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, glad to help @user122514 . They key was to escape `|` with double backslashes.

Comment: PS. If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by accepting the answer.